# Compact multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i've a similar array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Mario
        [type] => Doctor
        [operations] => brain
        [balance] => 3.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Luca
        [type] => Doctor
        [operations] => hearth
        [balance] => 6.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Luca
        [type] => Doctor
        [operations] => hands
        [balance] => 4.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Luca
        [type] => Doctor
        [operations] => foots
        [balance] => 1.00
    )

)
```

I must to merge it for id, so obtain only 2 elements for array (0 and 1) and Luca (id 3) must be unified for operations, in a new array, similar to this, so in future print more clearly operations unified and not divided.

```
[...]
)
[1] => Array
(
  [id] => 3
  [name] => luca
  [type] => doctore
  [operations] => Array (6.00 hearts,
                         4.00 hands,
                         1.00 foots)
```

)

I can not figure how solve my trouble... Someone could help me please? Thank you very much to all!

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$input = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Mario', 'type' => 'Doctor', 'operations' => 'brain', 'balance' => 3.00),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Luca', 'type' => 'Doctor', 'operations' => 'hearth', 'balance' => 6.00),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Luca', 'type' => 'Doctor', 'operations' => 'hands', 'balance' => 4.00),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Luca', 'type' => 'Doctor', 'operations' => 'foots', 'balance' => 1.00),
);

$output = array();

foreach ($input as $person)
{
    // Add the person to the output, if needed.
    if (array_key_exists($person['id'], $output) === false)
    {
        $output[$person['id']] = 
            array( 
                'id' => $person['id'],
                'name' => $person['name'],
                'type' => $person['type'],
                'operations' => array(),
            );
    }

    // Add the operation to the array of operations.
    $output[$person['id']]['operations'][] =
        array(
            'type' => $person['operations'],
            'balance' => $person['balance'],
        ));
}

foreach ($output as $person)
{
    if (count($person['operations']) === 1)
    {
        // If the array contains only 1 item, pull it out of the array.
        $output[$person['id']]['operations'] = $person['operations'][0];
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you, i'll study your solution! Btw, if I would merge only repeated id? How could you modify your code to obtain that only id==3 "has multidimensional array" on operations and not id==1 ? Thank you!

Comment: I've added an extra loop to do that. It lets the loop before create the multi-dimensional array, and then removes the extra dimension if the sub-array contains only 1 item. But this way it is harder to use the information, because you will have to check whether the information is directly in `['operation']` or one level deeper. Better leave it as it was, for easier processing.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this in a search newer than 2012, the OP mentions the word 'compact', but nowhere in here is there an answer related to the PHP compact function.